# Kafka OffsetOutOfRangeException even for offset ID zero

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My application is trying to poll the records from zero offset but I am getting below  error

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException
```

I am using simple apache consumer code something like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/writing-a-kafka-consumer-in-java) ,  generally this error should come when I poll with offeset with a number and it is removed or not exisst in kafka broker..
So any Idea why this error even for offest 0

Answer (score 1):

As you said, this error happens when the requested offset does not exist anymore in Kafka.

Offset 0 is not different. It can be deleted like any other offset when the retention limits are reached.

You can use the Consumer's [`beginningOffsets()`](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#beginningOffsets-java.util.Collection-) or Admin's [`listOffsets()`](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#listOffsets-java.util.Map-) APIs to find the beginning offsets for your topic.